# Glassfish deploy --libraries option does not recognize CDI beans

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3

I wanted to put jars on the classpath of a web applicaton by using the Glassfish 3

```
asadmin deploy --libraries
```

option. It works nicely except one strange thing. CDI beans does not seem to be recognized for this "bean deployment archive". When I put the same jar in the WEB-INF/lib of the deployed application and restart the server, the beans are recognized fine.

Has anyone had the same problem? Might this be a bug? Has anyone tried it in Glassfish 4?